# Not able to update data on BottomSheet from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

In my app there is this activity where data are shown in `RecyclerView`.

I have added the BottomSheetBehavior too. Here, I wanted to show user the `Data` which he or she has selected at the `RecyclerView`.

Here is the thing which makes it interesting that when I click on the `RecyclerView` the data loads on the Bottom sheet but after that again if I click on different **position** at `recyclerData` it's still loads the **previous** data not the different **position** `data`.

My query is how can I resolve this, I wanted to show particular click position data from recyclerview to BottomSheet.

It's not that I am not able to display but nomatter whichever position I click on `RecyclerView` the same data is being **Displayed** on BottomSheet

Here is my code **`onBindViewHolder`**:

```
 //RecyclerViewCode
    Glide.with(activity).load(data.getITEM_IMAGE()).error(R.drawable.googleg_standard_color_18)
            .into(holder.recyclerViewItemImageViewAdapter);

    holder.recyclerViewItemNameAdapter.setText(data.getITEM_NAME());
    holder.recyclerViewItemPriceAdapter.setText("₹ "+data.getITEM_PRICE());
    holder.recyclerViewTimeForPreparation.setText(data.getITEM_PREPARATION_TIME());
    holder.recyclerViewItemDescriptionAdapter.setText(data.getITEM_DESCRIPTION());

    if (!itemDataList.get(position).getAVAILABILITY().equals("false")){
        holder.itemUnavailability.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.recyclerViewItemAvailability.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        
        //BottomSheetBehavior Object:
        selectedItemFoodAvailability.setText("Available");
        selectedItemFoodAvailability.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#95C869"));

        if (itemDataList.get(position).getITEM_RATTING().equals("null")){

            holder.recyclerViewItemRattingAdapter.setText("--");
            holder.imageViewRattingStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }else{

            holder.recyclerViewItemRattingAdapter.setText(data.getITEM_RATTING());
            holder.imageViewRattingStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    }else{

        holder.itemUnavailability.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.itemUnavailability.setClickable(false);
        holder.recyclerViewItemAvailability.setText("Currently unavailable");
        holder.recyclerViewItemAvailability.setAllCaps(true);

    //BottomSheetBehavior Object:   
        selectedItemFoodAvailability.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FD7A49"));
        selectedItemFoodAvailability.setText("UNAVAILABLE");

    }

    //BottomSheetBehavior attaching RecyclerData
    selectedFoodName.setText(itemDataList.get(position).getITEM_NAME());
                    Glide.with(activity).load(itemDataList.get(position).getITEM_IMAGE()).error(R.drawable.googleg_standard_color_18)
                            .into(selectedItemFoodImage);
                    selectedItemFoodDescription.setText(itemDataList.get(position).getITEM_DESCRIPTION());
                    selectedItemFoodPrice.setText(itemDataList.get(position).getITEM_PRICE());
                    if (!itemDataList.get(position).getAVAILABILITY().equals("false")){
                        selectedItemFoodAvailability.setText("Available");
                        selectedItemFoodAvailability.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#95C869"));
                    }else{

                        selectedItemFoodAvailability.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FD7A49"));
                        selectedItemFoodAvailability.setText("UNAVAILABLE");
                    }


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View sheet= activity.findViewById(R.id.SelectedBottomSheetForFood);
            bottomSheetBehavior= bottomSheetBehavior.from(sheet);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

        }
    });

    selectedItemFoodShop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent= new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), Shop.class);
            intent.putExtra("uid", data.getCLIENT_UID());
            intent.putExtra("type",data.getTREE());
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    selectedItemFoodAddCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!data.getAVAILABILITY().equals("false")){
                Toast.makeText(activity, "item "+data.getITEM_NAME()+" added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to place order for selected Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me???
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to solve it by creating a method under the `Holder.ItemView.setOnClick` then passed the data on the Method created with the same code mentioned above and I worked. However, I didn't find any difference between the lines of code because it was the same as above just that in the new one everything related to BottomSheet was in the new Method otherwise it's just the same.